# Android - CircleButton Error

Tags: java, android, button, geometry

Following this library [CircleButton.java](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/at/markushi/ui/CircleButton.java), I get an error

> Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here

at line 57:

```
circlePaint.setColor(pressed ? pressedColor : defaultColor);
```

Any help on what should I do?

Comment: Welcome, to Stackoverflow! You can accept a helpful answer to give the user feedback that it really helped you. This is incentive both for you and the other user in a number of ways. After all, this is what keeps the site going!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the value of your `pressedColor` is similar to this `R.color.some_color_name`.

A correct way of retrieving color from resources is following:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.some_color_name);
```

In your case:

```
circlePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, pressed ? pressedColor : defaultColor));
```

**What's the difference???**

`R.id.some_color_name` is just an id from `R` class, that is being generated from your resources (`res` folder).

What you want is a color int, that is constructed by the value of the resource, that your resource id points to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass color of type `int`, precisely instance of `android.graphics.Color` since that is the one used in the `setColor` library method, not a resource ID.

If you want to construct a Color yourself, instead of using the default ones, look at [`int argb(red, green, blue, alpha)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for example.

For more information: [android.graphics.Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).